# AWS API gateway - How do you 500 on unhandled exceptions and 4XX/5XX on handled exceptions with a python lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I feel like this should be some pretty basic out-of-the-box functionality with API gateway, but [apparently it isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659170/api-gateway-500-response-on-unhandled-exception) The question is simple. I have a lambda written in python 3.6 and I want unhandled exceptions to appear as a 500 HTTP error code, and handled exceptions to appear as 4XX/5XX depending on the error message and regexs I have configured in my integration responses. And obviously successful runs of the lambda function should return 200 but we'll ignore that since 200 is the default response anyways.

Comment: Are you running the lambda from api gateway as proxy integration? If that is the case then you can and need to define all your errors and response codes in the returns within the lambda function.

Comment: I was not. I have switched to that now and it is working the way I want. I would still like this question answered though because proxy is almost an entirely different way of handling this relationship and I feel like this should have been possible without it. Once upon a time proxy didn't exist.

Comment: Ya. I personally have only done it via proxy. I like to handle things via code. But you are right API Gateway is designed to be able to deal with it. Hopefully someone has a solution to handle it the other way.